# Resizing an image in Processing2 on eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am new to Processing , and have been playing around with its features but can't for the life of me figure out how to resize an image properly. Below is an example of a function where from the tutorials, but I cant seem to resize the image properly so that it fits the window, has anyone any suggestion s ??

import processing.core.*;

```
public class Adjusting_image_brightness extends PApplet
{
    //intiallize image
    PImage img;
    public void setup()
    {
        //set the size
        size(320,240);
        //load the image
        img = loadImage("Conn4Board2.jpg");     
        //img.resize(400, 400);

    }
    public void draw()
    {
        //call the pixels
        loadPixels();
        //run through the pixels
        for(int x = 0; x < img.width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y <img.height ; y++)
            {
                //calculate the 1D pixel location 
                int loc = x + y*width;
                //get the R G B values from the picture
                float r = red(img.pixels[loc]);
                float b= blue(img.pixels[loc]);
                float g = green(img.pixels[loc]);

                //change the brightness acording to the mouse here
                double  adjustBrightness = ((float) mouseX / width) * 8.0;
                r *= adjustBrightness;
                b *= adjustBrightness;
                g *= adjustBrightness;


                    //Constrainr RGB to between 0 - 255
                    r = constrain(r, 0 , 255);
                    g = constrain(g, 0 , 255);
                    b = constrain(b, 0, 255);

                    //make a new colour and set pixel in the window 
                    int c = color(r,g,b);
                    pixels[loc] = c;

            }
        }
         updatePixels();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Stephen.

Comment: On a not-unimportant-note, you're technically writing a Java program that uses the Processing API, not a Processing program. (Pure Processing programs have a simpler programming model such as no visibility rules, global vars due to all the code ending up inside a single class, and technically no access to java libraries, though in practice when running in a JVM, the program will have)

Answer (score 0):

Too much code if all you want is to resize the image so it fits in the window. The **image()** function already lets you say which bounding box it should fit in, so just use this:

```
image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

and your image will draw scaled-to-fit.

Comment: Hi Mike , that didn't quite work, in that it only affects the way it is displayed. I was looking t Resize the image for processing. But the Resize(). was not working at all .. apparently it is a none bug. thanks anyway.